# if loop is leaving off last item

Tags: android, list, if-statement, arraylist, boolean

I have a list array of songs and i want to add all the songs that start with the same first letter to the same section.  This loop and method work except it leaves off the last song in songstoadd list array.

It is not an issue with the while loop the issue is with the if statement that checks the boolean.

```
Collections.sort(songtitle);

int m = 0;
ArrayList<String> songstoadd1 = new ArrayList<String>();
boolean stringsequal = true;
while( m <songtitle.size()-1){
    stringsequal = false;

    if(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1).equals(songtitle.get(m+1).substring(0, 1))){
        stringsequal = true;
        if(stringsequal){ // THis is the Issue
            songstoadd1.add(songtitle.get(m));
            songstoadd1.add(songtitle.get(m+1));  ///// This is where it leaves off last item in the list ////////////
            stringsequal = false;
            m++;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  songtitle.get(m) +"  " +  songtitle.get(m+1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        adapter.addSection(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1), new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songstoadd1));
        m+=songstoadd1.size();
    }else{
        ArrayList<String> songstoadd = new ArrayList<String>();
        songstoadd.add(songtitle.get(m));
        adapter.addSection(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1), new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songstoadd));
        m++;
    }

}
setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: `stringsequal = true;` is useless here, you test for it at the following line (so the test will always succeed, or there is a part of the code missing), and reset it before going out of the `if` block, and you do not use that variable at all anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop invariant is off by one. You need:  `while( m <songtitle.size()){`

Then since you're checking 1 ahead in your list, you can do this:

```
String lastChar =""; 
ArrayList<String> songsToAdd = new ArrayList<String>();

while(m < songtitle.size()){
    if(lastChar.equals(songtitle.get(m).substring(0,1)){
       songsToAdd.add(songtitle.get(m));
    }else{
       //if we're here, we need to start a new section so add everything we've already accumulated to the list view
       adapter.addSection(lastChar, new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songsToAdd));

       lastChar = songtitle.get(m).substring(0,1);
       songsToAdd = new ArrayList<String>();
       songsToAdd.add(songtitle.get(m));
    }  
m++; 
}


//now handle the last section
if(songsToAdd.size()>0){
    adapter.addSection(lastChar, new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songsToAdd));
```

Comment: I get a force close unless i have the -1 it has to be there

Comment: I think it's best to restructure what you're doing slightly. I updated my answer based on your updates.

Comment: Thanks but this is an infinite loop nothing happens do u know why

Comment: yeah, i forgot to increment m at the bottom of the loop. sorry about that. Response edited with fix.

Answer (score 3):

Your while loop is incorrect.

> while( m <songtitle.size()-1){

You're taking care of the zero index twice.

Either do <= OR remove the -1

Comment: Thank you but can u check the edits cause the problem is elsewhere

Comment: That is the fix to the problem you have asked. What error are you getting after making the change?

Answer (score 1):

that `m+=songstoadd1.size()` line seems completely off... `m++` would be sufficient.

if you have 3 songs starting with the same letter, the first pass of the loop will add the 2 first songs to the list, increment `m` (at the `m++` line), then add 2 to `m` (at the `m+=songstoadd.size()` line. then `m` is `3` and the loop exits.

note however that it may move the problem elsewhere... you'd better have an inner loop which increments `m` while the songs have the same first letter, and an outer loop which adds create the new section containing the songs found in the inner loop.

something like:

```
while( m < songtitle.size() ){
    n = m+1;
    songstoadd1.add(songtitle.get(m));
    while ( (n<songtitle.size()) && (songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1).equals(songtitle.get(n).substring(0, 1))) ){
            songstoadd1.add(songtitle.get(n));
            n++;
    }
    adapter.addSection(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1), new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.song, songstoadd1));
    songstoadd1.clear(); // i don't know if this method exists, anyway it should clear the list content
    m = n;
}
```

Comment: I deleted the m+=songstoadd1.size() and now it only gives me the last song in the list

Comment: @Waggoner_Keith: you have to replace the line with `m++`. but see my edit, an inner loop may be more clear.

Comment: Your method got a force close as well as every method who's while loop is not sontitle.size()-1

Comment: ??? where is the problem ??? `songtitle.size()` returns the size of the list, isn't it ? so if `m` is always below the size, there should be no problem ?

Answer (score 0):

How about changing

```
while( m <songtitle.size()-1){
```

to

```
while( m <songtitle.size()){
```

and

```
if(songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1).equals(songtitle.get(m+1).substring(0, 1))){
```

to

```
if(m == (songtitle.size()-1) &&
songtitle.get(m).substring(0, 1).equals(songtitle.get(m+1).substring(0, 1))){
```

You should use m < songtitle.size() in loop, but the following .get(m+1)'s will fail for the last element without this change.

Also the

```
m+=songstoadd1.size();
```

should probably be changed to

```
m++:
```

as far as I can understand.